# JPA, EclipseLink, PostgreSQL and schemas

Tags: postgresql, jpa, schema, eclipselink

I want to develop a Java EE application with JPA (EclipseLink implementation) and PostgreSQL as database.

I chose to have one database and multiples schemas instead of having multiples databases and one schema per database.

So, in my persistence.xml I have something like that :

```
<persistence-unit name="00" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>todo</jta-data-source>

    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="PostgreSQL" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="userpwd" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="01" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>todo</jta-data-source>

    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.target-database" value="PostgreSQL" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="userpwd" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I can easily reference persistence unit :

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("01");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

but how can I store information about schemas in persistence.xml ? I want to access schema `00` or `01` in `testdb` database.

I probably could change schema via native SQL directly but is there a way to bind schema to persistence unit ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA - EclipseLink - How to change default schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211138/jpa-eclipselink-how-to-change-default-schema)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This same question was asked and answered here:
[JPA - EclipseLink - How to change default schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211138/jpa-eclipselink-how-to-change-default-schema)

You can override the schema for the entire persistence unit using an orm.xml file, or define it within each table annotation or xml element as needed.

Comment: I was creating as many postgreSQL users that I have schemas and reassign default schemas of these users but your solution is definitly better. Thank you !