# How do I override the schema for a JPA app inside a web fragment from a web app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

So I have the following:

- [a web fragment](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/tree/master/doxdb-rest) that provides a REST API and uses JPA to deal with entities that can be embedded in an existing application.
- [an web application](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/tree/master/doxdb-sample-web) that has the [web fragment](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/tree/master/doxdb-rest) in `WEB-INF/lib`

I am trying to override the schema from the default to a different one from the [web application](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/tree/master/doxdb-sample-web)

I have tried combinations of:

- using `orm.xml` inside `WEB-INF`
- using `orm.xml` inside `META-INF`
- using `persistence.xml` inside `WEB-INF`
- using `persistence.xml` inside `META-INF`
- `persistence.xml` has `<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>`
- `persistence.xml` has `<mapping-file>WEB-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>`
- `persistence.xml` with `<persistence-unit name="same">`
- `persistence.xml` with `<persistence-unit name="different">`

To no avail.  I am trying to avoid touching the [web fragment](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/tree/master/doxdb-rest) and portable (so nothing EclipseLink specific like `SessionCustomizer`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize your persistence settings, you should not put `persistence.xml` inside your web fragment. Instead, define all the settings only in `persistence.xml` of your web application, plus add reference to your fragments jar using `jar-file` in the `persistence.xml` . You may define a default orm.xml file in your fragment that can be reused in web application's persistence.xml, but does not have to be.

In order to specify different default schema, define it in additional orm.xml file, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145436/jpa-missing-shema-on-insert/32161466#32161466). Remember that you may use more orm files for single persistence unit, you just need to name them differently. They will be searched for in classpath of the application including your fragment.

Comment: Nope didn't work, I tried to do as you had stated (even without an `orm.xml` file just the `persistence.xml` file) and I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null`

Comment: I also tried adding the `<jar-file>lib/dox-rest...jar</jar-file>` with no luck either.

Comment: You request an EM for unit named null somewhere. When I'll have time to look at your vode I will look into it

Comment: Thanks, I don't request anything named `null` but I am relying on the default which is given by `@PersistenceUnit` with no annotations parameters

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer, I sometimes forget this: persistence.xml always goes into the **META-INF** folder, not into WEB-INF. Try to remove `persistence.xml` from fragment and move it to META-INF folder in the webapp.

Comment: I played with the app a bit and got it working with my advice above plus adding jar-file element into the `persistence.xml` in the WAR to point to dox-rest jar to search for entities there.

Comment: This does not solve the "no modification of the web fragment" but it may be a the only way at the moment.  I have verified the solution and excepted this as the answer unless someone else can find another way :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88042/discussion-between-ondrejm-and-archimedes-trajano).